# Hide and Unhide TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to hide and unhide TinyMCE editor from a textarea where the user can opt to use tinyMCE or not.

For example, if I have a dropdown like this:

```
<label for="typed">HTML editor type</label>
<select name="typed" id="typed">
    <option value="tinymce">TinyMCE</option>
    <option value="notinymce">No TinyMCE</option>
</select>
```

Inspecting TinyMCE on my page, I noticed that there is no div id where I could possibly turn on or off.

What would be the best practice to hide and unhide the TinyMCE editor in the textarea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`tinymce.editor.hide()`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#hide) and [`tinymce.editor.show()`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#show).

Comment: Thanks for your input Ghadeer, but how would I implement it? Sorry, I'm new with this stuff.

Comment: Dear @ffas. First, you have to make a research about your problem then if you don't see a result that fit your needs, you'll publish a question here. Second, I gave you the links which you can follow to get your answer completely!